# The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found when running WinAppDriver test in MS Hosted Agent

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, azure-pipelines-yaml, winappdriver

I am running my test in the Azure Hosted Agent and the automation test is running fine locally.

But when I tried to run it in the DevOps pipeline, the test failed with The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found

[image]

I made sure that the setting in the pipeline have the right version of chromedriver variable to the hosted agent machine.

but still to no avail, I can replicate this is my chromedriver mismatched if tested locally on my machine.

What am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: does anyone have a clue about this 404 error?